# How to calculate new Pandas dataframe column with different functions according to other column entries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Given this dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[0.380,0.475,0.380,0.475,0.570],"B":[20,20,63,63,63]})

       A     B
0    0.380   20
1    0.475   20
2    0.380   63
3    0.475   63
4    0.570   63
```

I would like to add a column that returns the result of a function given the input of column A, but the function should vary based on the content of column B. Easy enough to add a column based on A using the apply method:

```
def conv(x):
    return (33.8*np.sin(1.65*(x-0.89))+33.9)/0.19
df['C']=df['A'].apply(conv)
df
```

but I'd like to apply a completely different function to A based on the entry in column B. Setting up any 'if' statements within the definition returns ValueErrors of course, and using `df['C'].isin([20])` gives me a list of boolean values. Next I'm going to try `df.groupby('B')` and apply different functions to each group, but I'm still wondering what is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Tell us how you'd like it to vary and what you think the results should be.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way of using `apply()` that can take more than one column of the `DataFrame`.  Here's an example of it below, with placeholders in all caps:

```
def conv(x, y):
    if y == SOME_VALUE_1:
        return (33.8*np.sin(1.65*(x-0.89))+33.9)/0.19
    else:
        return SOME_OTHER_FUNCTION_OF_X

df['C']=df.apply(lambda x : conv(x['A'], x['B']) , axis=1)
df
```

Notice how we are applying the function directly to the `DataFrame`, rather than to just one column of it.  The `lambda` picks out the correct columns and sends them to the function. The `axis=1` piece instructs pandas to apply the function column-wise (the default is row-wise).

Comment: This was my original idea, but I just didn't know how to set the conditional using the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

I created a second function (conv2) and assumed you wanted to calculate conv if column B was equal to 20, else conv2. I get the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0.380, 0.475, 0.380, 0.475, 0.570], "B": [20, 20, 63, 63, 63]})


def conv(x):
    return (33.8*np.sin(1.65*(x-0.89))+33.9)/0.19


def conv2(x):
    return 2.0 * x

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: conv(x.A) if (x.B == 20) else conv2(x.A), axis=1)
```

I get the following dataframe:

```
       A   B          C
0  0.380  20  45.775003
1  0.475  20  65.906299
2  0.380  63   0.760000
3  0.475  63   0.950000
4  0.570  63   1.140000
```

Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: That works. I am still learning how to use lambda functions for conditionals

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up this way

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=np.arange(8),
        B=list('wxyz') * 2
    ))

dof = dict(
    w=lambda j: j + 2,
    x=lambda j: j ** 2 - 1,
    y=lambda j: math.sin(j),
    z=lambda j: abs(math.log2(j))
)

df.apply(lambda x: dof[x.B](x.A), 1)

0     2.000000
1     0.000000
2     0.909297
3     1.584963
4     6.000000
5    24.000000
6    -0.279415
7     2.807355
dtype: float64
```